# Upgrading OpenGL (Intel Celeron 1037U)

Tags: intel-graphics, opengl

This is my current computer's specification :

- Intel Celeron CPU 1037U
- Intel HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1)
- OpenGL ES 3.0
- Mesa 20.0.8
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit

I want to install OBS, which is requiring [OpenGL 3.3](https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#linux)

According to [this](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/71995/intel-celeron-processor-1037u-2m-cache-1-80-ghz.html), Intel Celeron 1037U is part of Intel Celeron 1000 Series. And according to [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html), Intel Celeron 1000 Series can support up to OpenGL 4.

Now how can i upgrade my OpenGL?

Comment: Post results of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL core"`

Comment: @doug OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:

Comment: Have you actually tried to run the app yet, no reason why it shouldn't work, or at least open.

Comment: @doug 

Yes. It actually works. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the root of problem is that i can't check my OpenGL version correctly.

This is the full output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"` on my machine :

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500 (IVB GT1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I thought that my OpenGL version was 3.0 (OpenGL version string). It turns out there are two OpenGL version here, 3.0 and 4.2 (core profile).

According to [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types), on OpenGL 3.0, many OpenGL functions were declared deprecated. OpenGL 3.1 removed almost all the deprecated functionality in OpenGL 3.0. In 3.2, OpenGL was split into two : core and compatibility.  In the compatibility profile, the deprecated feature is still accessible, but we can't access the newer feature. The new features are implemented on the core profile, but the deprecated feature is removed.

This is probably similar to Python 2.7 vs Python 3.x. All past's deprecated features is still accessible if we are using 2.7, but we can't access the newer features. If we want to use the newer features, use 3.x, but we can't access the deprecated features.

In short, 3.0 is probably the compatibility version, and 4.3 is the core version. This is already satisfied the OBS's requirement (4.3 > 3.3). My OBS is working properly now.

Why glxinfo bothers displaying two version at once (3.0 and 4.3)? Probably because OpenGL makes it mandatory to implement the core, but the compatibility is not guaranteed to be available. By displaying two version at once, it tells us that this OpenGL implementation supports both compatibility profile and core profile.